# jquery: Remove hover on initial page load if mouse is over element

Tags: jquery, hover, pageload

I have a menu that shows the submenu on hover.  My problem is that when the page loads, if the mouse is over any of the menu elements then the hover event will fire.  What I would like to happen is that on initial page load the hover event will not fire if the mouse is over one of the menu elements; if the mouse is not over a menu element then the normal hover event would fire once the user mouse's over a menu element.

Thanks in advance for any and all help,
B

Answer (score 1):

@Mörre idea is good, here's a inspired one, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // sets a loaded class on your menu when DOM is loaded (you could also try the $(window).load event)
    $('#menu').addClass('loaded');

    // add the hover event on the links of your menu only if the menu has the loaded class
    $('#menu.loaded a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
                if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                    // do something on mouseover
                } else {
                    // do something on mouseout
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: this is what I originally had, the issue we were running into is was that if the mouse was not over the element on page load then when the user first hovered over that element the hover wouldn't fire.  
What I'm trying to do is basically unbind hover if the mouse is over the element once the page loads.

Comment: Ah, sorry, we need to use live(), otherwise the class is added later and $('#menu.loaded a') doesn't exist at the time we define the hover event. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default behavior for the hover element from firing.

```
$("menuElementSelector").hover(function(e){
 e.PreventDefault();
});
```

Comment: but how would I do this only when the page loads and only if the mouse is over that element?

Answer (score 0):

use [hoverIntent jquery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). You can delay de reponse of the event. So, when the mouse is over, the event won´t be trigger immediately.

Comment: The desired result is not to delay the hover event, but to unbind it completely if the mouse is initially over a menu element when the page loads.

Comment: but I think is an untrusive method, 1. to achieve what do want and 2. avoid mouse hover mistakes